# How to avoid showing to users errors of type SQLSTATE?

Tags: error-handling, global-configuration

I try to avoid showing this type of messages to the user

[image]

I have tried to do it by modifying the global configuration but without success, I specifically modified the options Global configuration> System> Debug system I set the value to no, and in Global configuration> Server> Error reporting the value to none, although I understand this is related to logs.

I also found that in the file `templates/fontaine_j3_temp/error.php` where fontaine_j3_temp corresponds to active template I can modify the error output, but I would like to know if it is possible to do it through the Joomla configuration without perhaps the need to modify templates.

Maybe configure the joomla instance to only show this type of errors in development and some modified error message in production.

Thanks for the suggestions

Update 1:

Or this type of error message displayed as flash messages

[image]

For this type of message, I thought of some kind of core event that could intersect with a plugin

Comment: Edit the error.php in your template. Give a redirect to your /page-not-found with an 404 for example. So no errors are shown at all.